# Can't solve memory management (valgrind) in this c program

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

My problem is as follows. I have to create a C program that concatenates all the parameters in input in one buffer and then this return this buffer. My solution works, but there are memory management issues.

How can I fix the problem?

```c
#define RIALLOCA(buf, newsize) buf = realloc(buf, newsize);

char *mystrcat(char *buf, size_t sz, char *first, ...) {
    va_list l;
    va_start(l, first);

    buf = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);

    if (sz < strlen(first) + 1) {
        sz += (strlen(first) + 1);
    }

    RIALLOCA(buf, sz + 1 + 16);
    strncat(buf, first, strlen(first));

    char *nextString = va_arg(l, char *);

    while (nextString != NULL) { 
        // sz += strlen(nextString);
        RIALLOCA(buf, strlen(buf) + strlen(nextString) + 1 + 16);
        strncat(buf, nextString, strlen(nextString));
        nextString = va_arg(l, char *);
    }   

    va_end(l);

    return buf;
}   

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 7) {
        printf("troppi pochi argomenti\n");
        return -1; 
    }   
    char *buffer = NULL;
    RIALLOCA(buffer, 16);  // macro che effettua l'allocazione
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    buffer = mystrcat(buffer, 16, argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5],
                      argv[6], NULL);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);     
    return 0;
}
```

This is problem with Valgrind

[image]

Comment: do not post links to images.  Rather copy/paste the text into your question.

Comment: it is a waste of your time (and ours) to generate 'replacement' functions (or `#defines`) for C library functions

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()`, 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2)  when calling `realloc()`, always assign the result to a temporary pointer then check for (!=NULL) otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the original pointer is lost, resulting in a unrecoverable  memory leak

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: When posting code, please post the `#include` statements, so we do not have guess as to which header files your code actually includes

Comment: regarding: `if (argc != 7) { printf("troppi pochi argomenti\n"); return -1; }`  1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) when the number of command line parameters is not correct then output to `stderr` (not `stdout`)  a USAGE statement similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <describe each parameter>\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding: `buf = realloc(buf, sz + 1 + 16);
 strncat(buf, first, strlen(first));`   What happens when the first parameter is more thatn 32 bytes in length?   >>  the allocated array 'buf' is overflowed, resulting in undefined behavior.   Suggest obtaining the length of 'first' then performing the reallocation.

Comment: you r program can be corrected and simplified a lot, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that - when you call `buf = malloc()` inside `mystrcat()` - you are causing a memory leak. Memory had already been dynamically allocated for `buf` within your `main()`.

Change

```c
buf = malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
```

to

```c
buf = realloc(buf, strlen(buf) + 1);
```

Also ... I agree with user3629249: providing macros for standard library functions in the way you have done seems redundant - at least in this context.

Answer (score 0):

in function: `mystrcat()`

This statement:

```
buf = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
```

is not correct.  Because `buf` is already a pointer to allocated memory AND this is not modifying the pointer `buf` back in the `main()` function but rather just the parameter on the stack.

To correct:

in `main()` (notice the additional '&' on parameter: `buffer`)

```
buffer = mystrcat(&buffer, 16, argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], 
argv[5], argv[6], NULL);
```

in `mystrcat()` remove this line

```
buf = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
```

regarding:

```
if(sz < strlen(first) + 1)
{
    sz += (strlen(first) + 1);
}
```

since `sz` contains 16 and the first character in `buf` is '\0'  This `if()` statement will never be entered.

Since the passed parameter `buf` is now a pointer to a pointer, due to the change in `main()`, the signature should be:

```
char* mystrcat(char **buf, size_t sz, char *first, ...)
```

and all references to `buf` should be de-referencing that parameter to access the pointer value in `main()`

There is plenty more, but the above are the underlying problems